# Alfresco as App development framework?

Tags: frameworks, alfresco, development-environment

I was surfing the Internet where I found an article saying that Alfresco is a Content Management Framework as well as App Development Framework. While I understood it as Content Management Framework, I am not able to know about it as an App Development Framework.I tried researching over it, but could not find anything viable.

I want to know that how Alfresco can be used as an App Development Framework ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Alfresco has an application development framework, more info here:

- Guides: https://community.alfresco.com/community/application-development-framework/pages/get-started
- Angular 2 components repository: https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-ng2-components
- Alfresco App Yeoman generator: https://github.com/Alfresco/generator-ng2-alfresco-app
- JavaScript API repository: https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-js-api

Some videos:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OFI3izSDdk
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjOgVbINAyU

In case you want a live support you can use the Gitter channel: https://gitter.im/Alfresco/alfresco-ng2-components

Answer (score 3):

Well, if for App is meant mobile application, Alfresco has a [Mobile SDK](https://www.alfresco.com/develop/mobile) available for both iOS and Android which can help you create your own application to work against the Alfresco Platform.

Moreover there is another framework called [Aikau](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/aikau-intro.html) which has one main goal

> The main purpose of Aikau is to provide a library of widgets that can be easily assembled into a web application for accessing an Alfresco repository. The aim is not to replace Share but it was necessary to migrate away from its original implementation, which was based around the Surf paradigms of pages, templates, components and web scripts, towards a solution that provided for rapid development and customization.

This feature was first introduiced in Alfresco 4.2 and then extended in Alfresco 5.0

Comment: Thanks...but if my app means a web application ? Will Alfresco support it as Web Application Development Framework ?

Comment: I personally think that Alfresco is not a general purpose web application development framework. They have just created some frameworks in order to simplify web application creation when they have to interact with the Alfresco platform. At least this is my experience.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build applications for Alfresco you have a number of options available to you - as mentioned you can build mobile applications (and there are [SDKs available](https://www.alfresco.com/develop/mobile) to do this).

If you want to build web applications then you have the option of either customizing the default Alfresco Share client (which is built on top of the Alfresco Surf framework using a combination of YUI 2 and [Aikau](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau)). Alternatively you can built your own web client by building a new client with the [Maven Aikau Archetype](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/blob/master/tutorial/chapters/Tutorial1.md).

The advantage of the Surf framework is that it takes care of Alfresco authentication across all the various APIs (WebScript, CMIS, Public API, etc) as well as providing lots of security benefits (CSRF, XSS white-lists, etc).

The advantage of using Aikau is that it provides a large number of out-of-the-box widgets that are specifically designed to work with Alfresco data and address Alfresco (ECM) specific use cases.

You are of course not limited to these options - you can build an application on top of any stack you wish, but ultimately you will want to be making use of the REST APIs that the Alfresco Repository provides.

Depending upon the application you are building you may also want to build custom data models and build in workflow via Activiti BPM as well.